# sendgrid webapi with attachment

Tags: javascript, sendgrid

i am using sendgrid webapi to send mail from html page through ajax call. Everything is working fine but how to attach uploaded image to email.
i had checked sendgrid official documents there they described as files[filename.jpg]=filename.jpg. i had tried to pass local path with file name and also binary data to right side parameter but both not working.
Here is my code:

```
var queryString="api_user=anand123&api_key=*****&to=anand@gmail.com&subject=SignUp&html="+data+"&from="+email+"&files[main.jpg]=@"+filedata;



    $.ajax({
    type: "POST",
    url: "https://api.sendgrid.com/api/mail.send.json",
    data: queryString,
    crossDomain: true,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    contentType: "application/jsonp"
    });




var filedata;
function showUpload(val){

    var file=$('input[name=file_attach]')[0].files[0];
    create_blob(file, function(blob_string) {
    filedata=blob_string;
     });
    function create_blob(file, callback) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function() { callback(reader.result) };
    reader.readAsDataURL(file);
    } 
    };
```

Anyone have idea how to send attachment with email through sendgrid web Api?

Answer (score 0):

Sending email from client side code is a bad idea. Anyone can look at your code and see the credentials, and then send spam via your account. It will use up your email credits and get you banned from sending.